# C# - Get array values from object in Dictionary of type string, object

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type  which contains an array of objects which have two decimal property values. For clarity it looks like this:

[image]

How do I access the values of those Easting and Northing values ?

Comment: ((Coordinates)values[CoordinatesIndex].value).Easting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get just two values:

```
  var easting = values["Coordinates"][0].Easting;
  var northing = values["Coordinates"][0].Northing;
```

Explanation: since `values` is a *dictionary*:

```
  values["Coordinates"]            - get value (i.e. array) of "Coordinates" key
  values["Coordinates"][0]         - get 1st item of the array of "Coordinates" key
  values["Coordinates"][0].Easting - get Easting property of ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var coordinates =(Coordinates[])values["Coordinates"];
Console.WriteLine(coordinates[0].Easting);
Console.WriteLine(coordinates[0].Northing);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `values` be the Dictonary and the `"Coordinates"` is a Key inside it. So that we can access the associated values with this key by using `values["Coordinates"]`. In your case the value will be a collection(Array). So To access those values you need to Specify its index or you can iterate through the collection to get it's values.
     As you already said it was a `Dictonary<string,Object>` You need to cast the object to get the Business object. If so you can use The following snippet:

```
var currentEasting = (Coordinates[])(values["Coordinates"][0]).Easting;
```

If the collection is defined like `Dictonary<string,Coordinates>`  then you need not to cast. Can access it directly like this:

```
 var currentEasting = values["Coordinates"][0].Easting;
```

You can also iterate through those Values; this code will help you to do that:

```
foreach (Coordinates Co in values["Coordinates"])
{
   // access each values 
   var someEasting = Co.Easting
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear how the dictionary is defined. If it is defined as `Dictionary<string, object>`, you will either have to use reflection to get data from the value, or you will have to do a hard-coded cast:

```
var coords = (Coordinates[])values["Coordinates"];
var firstEast = coords[0].Easting;
```

This will of course fail if the object is not of type Coordinates.

If the dictionary is defined as `Dictionary<string, Coordinates[]>`, then it is simple:

```
var firstEast = values["Coordinates"][0].Easting;
```